# Spring Webflux Websocket closing before onErrorResume logic can be completed

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-websocket

I have a simple server that handles some very basic messages and returns an error message if there is a problem. However, when an error mono is returned, the connection is closed before the onErrorResume logic can be completed (I can see the connection is closed before the logging of the onErrorResume).

Here is the code in question, where `session` is a `WebSocketSession`:

```
session.send(
    session.receive()
        .map(messageConverter::read)
        .flatMap { messageHandlerStrategy.handle(it, session) }
        .onErrorResume {
            logger.error(it) { "Error happened handling message from client with the message" }
            if (it.message != null) {
                AlertMessage(it.message!!)
            } else {
                AlertMessage("Unknown error occurred")
            }.toMono()
        }
        .filter {
            logger.info { "Filtering if is Message: ${it is Message<Any>}" }
            it is Message<Any>
        }
        .cast(Message::class.java)
        .map { messageConverter.write(session, it) }
        .doFinally { logger.info { "${session.id} CLOSE." } }
        .log()
)
```

So if the `messageHandlerStrategy` returns a `Mono.error`, the expectation is that it will be wrapped in an AlertMessage and returned.

For clarity, I'm using Kotlin with Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE and allowing it to bring in the correct versions of everything (e.g. `reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE`).

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I was being stupid. As a `Mono.error` is being returned form `messageHandlerStrategy.handle`, the `onErrorResume` is completing the publisher it is subscribed to and creating a new publisher for everything else to subscribe to. So the `session.receive` publisher is being completed, therefore closing the session. I simply updated the `messageHandlerStrategy.handle` to return a relevant `Mono` of `AlertMessage` to then be sent back. Not sure how this would be possible if I didn't have control over the offending class.

For reference, I figured this out from the JavaDoc (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.util.function.Function-), specifically where it states "Subscribe to a fallback publisher when an error matching the given type occurs, using a function to choose the fallback depending on the error." and with the diagram, shows that a new publisher is being used.

Edit: An alternative is to set the `onErrorResume` inside the `flatMap` (so it's subscribed to the `messageHandlerStrategy.handle` publisher). It then looks like:

```
session.send(
    session.receive()
        .map(messageConverter::read)
        .flatMap { 
            messageHandlerStrategy.handle(it, session)
                .onErrorResume { throwable ->
                    logger.error(throwable) { "Error happened handling message from client with the message" }
                    if (throwable.message != null) {
                        AlertMessage(throwable.message!!)
                    } else {
                        AlertMessage("Unknown error occurred")
                    }.toMono()
                }
        }
        .filter {
            logger.info { "Filtering if is Message: ${it is Message<Any>}" }
            it is Message<Any>
        }
        .cast(Message::class.java)
        .map { messageConverter.write(session, it) }
        .doFinally { logger.info { "${session.id} CLOSE." } }
        .log()
)
```